# ST-LINK v2 can't connect

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, programming, st-link

I am having trouble with my ST-LINK V2 clone (USB stick look alike.)
Error is :

> Can not connect to target! If you're trying to connect to an STM32W1xx device, please select Normal or HotPlug mode from Target->Settings menu.
>
> If you're trying to connect to a low frequency application, please select a lower SWD Frequency mode from Target->Settings menu.

I have installed the ST-LINK utility and drivers and U have managed to update my ST-LINK version but I can't connect to target. I am trying to flash vtx device [OVX303](https://www.happymodel.cn/index.php/2021/07/27/happymodel-ovx300-ovx303-5-8g-40ch-300mw-vtx-openvtx/7-51/) "fpv drone video transmitter". The pinout for flashing is at the link.

my question is how to fix this error and flash device.

Here is my connection:

[image: connection]

Comment: what is your specific question?

Comment: Is that ST-Link a cheap clone from eBay? If so, I have run into multiple issues with them. Consider getting an original ST-Link since STM has been trying to push those clones out of the market

Comment: Does the clone programmer otherwise work? Is the camera even programmable, it might have SWD/JTAG disabled?

Comment: @DanielMelendrez my question is how to fix this error and make it work

Comment: @Justme i haven't tried it yet this is my first 'job'. I am guessing its working because i can update its firmware. Its not disabled, vtx is open source and it can be flashed.

Comment: How do you know it's supposed to be connected like that? Why the supply is 5V to the programmed board?

Comment: @Justme i have followed instructions for connecting it to st link. Its working on 5v.

Comment: A real ST-Link won't output 5V or 3.3V. Or even in special case when it does, it is not supposed to be used as it can't provide a lot of current. How much, if any, can your clone give out current and will the module work with that amount? Have you measured that supply voltage is properly connected and powering the target board? And other wires too?

Comment: @Justme i have not measured current but both devices have their led's on so i would assume its enough power. also i have been following [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JsJOMwu4hBM&t=125s) and he did the same.

Comment: @jsotola my question is how to fix this error and flash device.

Comment: The error may be in connections so the error is fixed by making sure everything is connected and powered properly. No software magic will make the problem go away if you have a problem in the hardware. Although you mentioned the clone got an firmware update. If the clone hardware does not support the latest firmware then it may not work. It's a clone so official firmwares don't have to work on clone products and the firmware updater can't know if you are uploading a new firnware to an unsupported clone hardware.

Comment: @macak the question belongs in the post at the top of this page ... it goes not belong in a comment where you put it ... please use the edit button and update your post

Comment: First step: try manually hold MCU in reset. Next step if first did not succeed: If you have logic analyzer you can try probing SWDIO and SWCLK signals. Both must change state between 0 and 1 several times and SWCLK must look like clock. My personal opinion is that issue is with your programmer like many other already mentioned. Do you have Raspberry Pi? Raspberry Pi and OpenOCD can program STM32 using Raspberry Pi GPIO but it requires tricky configuration and also OpenOCD has some bugs, especialy older version which you find in OS repository.